# Azure data factory SQL Server connection error code 9056

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Does anybody now what this error code means? I'm getting this error when trying to connect to an on-premise SQL Server from Azure data factory

Answer (score 0):

There's an incident around the the time you posted, and it has been mitigated now.

According to the [Azure status history](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/history/), can you manually restart your self-hosted Integration Runtime and try again?